# How to bind data in dropdown using jquery?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-core

This is my code. function AddRow is called when clicking a button "Add Item". After debugging i found out that ajax call is not executing , what is the issue with this?

```
function AddRow() {
            debugger;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataSource: [@(JavascriptArray(Model.Categories.Select(x => new { CategoryId = x.CategoryId,Category=x.Category, Display = $"{x.Category}" }).OrderBy(x => x.Display)))],
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (res) {
                    debugger;
                    $.each(res.d, function (data, value) {
                        $("#category").append($("<option></option>").val(value.categoryId).html(value.category));
                    });
                }

            });

                var row = "<tr>" +
                    "<td><input type='text' style='max-width: 300px' id='title' class='form-control' /></td>" +
                    "<td><select class='form-control' style='width: 120px;height:38px' id='category'><option value='0'></option></select></td>" +
                    //"<td><input type='text' style='max-width: 90px' name='category' id='category' class='form-control' placeholder='Category...' /></td>" +
                    "<td><input type='number' style='max-width: 75px' id='price' min=0 class='form-control' /></td>" +
                    "<td><input type='number' style='max-width: 75px' id='quantity' min=0 class='form-control' /></td>" +
                    "<td><input type='button' value='Add' onclick='addItem()' class='btn btn-success'/>&nbsp&nbsp" +
                    "<input type='button' value='Cancel' onclick='deleteNewItem(this)'name='removeLines[0]' class='btn btn-danger'  />"  +
                    "</td>" +
                    "</tr>";
                $('#CartTableBody').prepend($(row));

        }
```

I have updated url with action method that is providing data but still alert error message is shown

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            debugger;
            $.ajax({
                type: "Get",
                url: "@Url.Action("GetCategory", "Release")",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (res) {
                    debugger;
                    $.each(res.d, function (data, value) {
                        $("#category").append($("<option></option>").val(value.categoryId).html(value.category));
                    });
                },
                error: function (Result) {
                    alert("Error");
                }

            });
        })
```

Comment: Any errors in developer console? try debug this one: `$.ajax({...}).done(function(response){}).fail(function(error){})`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the jquery ajax function doesn't contain the datasource parameter.

I suggest you could use F12 browser develop tool to check the details error message when you click the `Add Item` button.

Besides, the ajax will contain the url which let your client post some message to the server side and server side return response to the client side.

If you want to know how to use ajax to append row to a table, I suggest you could refer to this [example](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Add-Delete-Rows-from-HTML-Table-using-jQuery-AJAX-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx).

Comment: If datasource can't be used how can i bind the data that is coming from a procedure call (from query handler function), to the dropdown

Comment: You should use sql query to query the database and return the model inside the action method.  Asp.net core will convert the model data to json data to the client side and then inside the success method you could bind that json  to the dropdownlist by using the js codes.

Comment: Could you please share your `Url.Action("GetCategory", "Release")` action codes? Which result it returned?

Answer (score 0):

```
           $.ajax({
                url: "YourUrl",
                type: "YourMethod",
                data: {
                },
            }).done(function (data) {
                var dropdown= $("#dropdown");
                    dropdown.html("");
                _.each(data, function (item) {
                    dropdown.append("<option value = '" + item.id+ "'>" + item.value+ "</option>");
                });
         
            }).fail(function (ex) {
                alert("Error");
            });
```